# Selecting highest rows on matrix pandas python.

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have the following data:

https://github.com/antonio1695/Python/blob/master/nearBPO/facturasb.csv

It is a matrix like the following example:

```
UUID  A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I  
1.1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
1.2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1.3   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
1.4   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1
1.5   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
1.6   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0 
1.7   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0 
1.8   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
1.9   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
```

I would like to make a new matrix with only the 50 highest columns (3 in the example) and it's respective UUID. With the highest columns i mean those columns that have more 1's in the matrix.

If i'm not clear enough, don't hesitate asking. Thank you.

Comment: Still, not clear. highest across or down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
df[df.sum().nlargest(3).index]
```

[image]

---

To exclude rows with all zeros among the n largest

```
n = df.sum().nlargest(3).index
df1 = df.loc[:, n]
df1[df1.eq(1).any(1)]
```

[image]

---

#### Setup

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = """UUID  A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I  
1.1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
1.2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1.3   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
1.4   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1
1.5   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
1.6   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0 
1.7   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0 
1.8   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
1.9   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), index_col=0, delim_whitespace=True)
```

---

#### Bonus solution with numpy

Assuming same setup (this is probably quicker)

```
n = df.values.sum(0).argsort()[-3:][::-1]
m = (a[:, n] == 1).any(1)

df.iloc[m, n]
```

***Notice*** the columns are not the same as my other solution.  That is because the multiple columns summed to the same value.

[image]

---

#### Timing

[image]

Comment: Is there a way for 1.3 to not be in that matrix?

Comment: I get the following error:    "Cannot use method 'nlargest' with dtype object"   @piRSquared

Comment: If the UUID happens to be a float and not a string -  don't forget to exclude it from the sum here...

Comment: In that case you can do something like `df[df.ix[:, 1:].sum().nlargest(50).index.insert(0, 'UUID')]`

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz make sure `UUID` is the index.  If it isn't, you can do `df.set_index('UUID', inplace=True)`.  If your `dtypes` are object, then most likely your values are strings.  Convert them with `df = df.astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this task into two parts. First, find which columns have the most `1`'s. Second, select only those columns.

Here's some data:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: import string

In [4]: data = np.random.randint(2, size=(10, 10))

In [5]: data
Out[5]:
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]]) 

In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list(string.ascii_lowercase[:10]))

In [7]: df.index.name = 'uuid'

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
      a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
uuid
0     1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
1     1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
2     0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
3     0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0
4     0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
5     0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1
6     0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
7     1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1
8     0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1
9     0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1
```

Now let's find the columns with the most `1`'s.

```
In [9]: df.sum()
Out[9]:
a    3
b    5
c    6
d    9
e    7
f    5
g    4
h    4
i    5
j    4
dtype: int64

In [10]: df.sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
Out[10]:
d    9
e    7
c    6
i    5
f    5
b    5
j    4
h    4
g    4
a    3
dtype: int64
```

Get the names of the first 3 of those.

```
In [11]: df.sum().sort_values(ascending=False).index[:3]
Out[11]: Index(['d', 'e', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

Use those names to select columns from the original dataframe.

```
In [12]: selection = df.sum().sort_values(ascending=False).index[:3]

In [13]: df[selection]
Out[13]:
      d  e  c
uuid
0     1  0  1
1     1  0  1
2     1  1  0
3     0  1  0
4     1  0  0
5     1  1  0
6     1  1  1
7     1  1  1
8     1  1  1
9     1  1  1
```